# parsing the xml now gives me an error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

here is my ajax call

```
$j.ajax({
  url: "http://www.earthtools.org/timezone/40.71417/-74.00639",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  complete: function(data){
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

the url returns back xml but I need to use jsonp to avoid cross site scripting....any ideas on how to avoid this error

```
missing ; before statement
[Break On This Error]   

<timezone xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceS...

-74.00...7653717 (line 2, col 10)
```

Any ideas...i need the localtime out of this call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not get xml cross domain in javascript due to cross domain policies...there are 100's of similar threads on SO

You can use a proxy if API doesn't deliver jsonp. Another handy tool is Yahoo YQL. They have a sandbox console can set your url up in minutes and get a YQL url to get data from in choice of xml or jsonp

Comment: how do i use a proxy in this situation and also how will Yahoo YQL help

Comment: YQL is free and fast. Proxy is file on your server using CURL to get the xml from other url and output it....make ajax call to that file. Not a lot of coding involved. Also with YQL can filter the other data file if wanted. You make call to the YQL usrl you set up in their sandbox

Comment: if using php you can set up proxy in one line for dev purposes...  `echo file_get_contents( 'urltodata'); ` but CURL better for error handling

Comment: Im using rails...so i will prob do a curl request and parse out the localtime and make a call my server

Comment: once you do it once will be painless going forward